# automatically show ribbon on publishing site

Tags: publishing-site, ribbon

I have a custom publishing site (custom masterpage and custom site definition). I want ribbon automatically be shown on new sites. So the users don't have to enable it through Site Settings:

[image]

So it should be like in this image:

[image]

Where can I define these options?

Comment: i have the same problem... so solution found yet?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet. If you find something, please add an answer here.