# Why is the ribbon different for users with the same permissions?

Tags: permissions, publishing-site, ribbon

I have a published site.  I have given 2 users Read permissions to that site.  On user can see the browse and page tabs (tho most options are disable {like the should be}), the other user does not have that tab.  I know there must be security settings somewhere for this but since I am new to this I am not sure where to look.
Thanks

Comment: sounds to me like one user is an external user and the other internal...have a look at site settings > Users and Permissions

Comment: thanks I check the security again but they are both set the same (both are internal) There must a setting somewhere..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a publishing site (like i think you said it is), each user can decide whether to hide or display the ribbon.  Maybe one user has selected to show it and the other one has decided to hide it.

See this old question for some screenshots:  [automatically show ribbon on publishing site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20619/automatically-show-ribbon-on-publishing-site)

EDIT:

Are both users in the Site Members group?  See this link:  http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/site-actions-menu-in-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: The users that don't have the ribbon also don't have the site settings menu.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my response.

Comment: Thanks very helpful.. I am getting closer.. I have a group that I can access under Site Actions | Site Settings | Users and Permissions |People and groups It seems when I add user to this group they behave as expected.  So I is this my Site Members Group? and if so where would I find the Site Visitors Group?

Comment: Never mind if found it duh! Right in front of my face!

Comment: One more question. I see I have the 3 groups Site Owners, Site Members and Site visitors. From what I been reading Owners have full control, members have contribute and visitors have read. What confuses me is that if I put my user in member that user does not have contribut rights to anything on my site (other than now he has the ribbon - with most options grayed out).

Comment: By default those are the permissions that SP sets but they can be changed.

Comment: Sorry - I still must be missing something. if I add my user to Site members .. I do NOT add that group to my site.  My user is added to that site thru a different group that only has read access but since he is the member of Site Members he can see the ribbon.  If I take him out of site members he does not.  Keep in mind he does not have access to update anything and Site members is not added to my site permissions.  This is strickly adding a person to the sharepoint member group. Seems odd

Comment: So normally, when a new site is created SharePoint will create the site owners, site members, and site visitor groups and typically will grant them full control, contribute and read access respectively.  You can then always change the permissions that these groups have on your site or even they have no permissions.  But because the groups are associated with your site, it seems that the members group gets some special treatment, like being able to see site actions and show the ribbon.